# Interfacing a Rpi with absolute encoder using RS-422 (SSI)

Tags: hardware, communication

So I am working on a project that requires me reading from an absolute encoder. It uses SSI (RS-422 protocol) and the datasheet is the following: https://www.hohner-elektrotechnik.de/upload/data-sheet-series-pzk-eng_1652102278.pdf . For my application I would need around 140 queries per second.

I was thinking on using a Raspberry Pi 4+ to query it, but I am a bit lost in terms of what to do/whether this is feasible/whether I need more hardware or not. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use RS-422 you will need an adapter which supports this protocol.

RS-422 uses differential signalling with different voltage levels to GPIO.